# Properly loading Template.templateName.rendered data context

Tags: javascript, d3.js, meteor

I have a template, `chartEditPreview`, that runs a D3.js chart-drawing function once the rendered callback fires. It looks like this:

```
Template.chartEditPreview.rendered = function() {
  drawChart(".chart-container", this.data);    
}
```

Where `.chart-container` is the target div and `this.data` is the data for the object in the DB currently being accessed. Problem is, `this.data` often returns `null`, seemingly at random. It looks like this has something to do with how the publish/subscribe pattern works — Iron Router (which I'm using) lets the templates render and then hot-pushes the data into those templates.

My question is (hopefully) pretty simple: how can I make sure `this.data` is actually full of DB data before `drawChart` is run? Should I be doing this in some other way, instead of calling it on the rendered callback?

I'm thinking of storing the DB data in a `Session` variable during the routing and calling that from rendered, but it seems like an extra step, and I'm not certain it'll fix this problem. The chart's also not rendered only once on the page — it's interactive, so it needs to be redrawn every time the database object is updated via one of the inputs on screen.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

---

For reference, here's what my routes.js looks like:

```
Router.route('/chart/edit/:_id', {
  name: 'chart.edit',
  layoutTemplate: 'applicationLayout',
  yieldRegions: {
    'chartEditType': { to: 'type' },
    'chartEditPreview': { to: 'preview' },
    'chartEditOutput': { to: 'output' },
    'chartEditAside': { to: 'aside' },
    'chartEditEmbed': { to: 'embed' }
  },
  data: function () {
    return Charts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  },
  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('chart', this.params._id);
  }
});
```

And my publications.js:

```
Meteor.publish("chart", function (id) {
  return Charts.find({ _id: id });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with Meteor. While the subscription might be ready (you should check for it like Ethaan shows) , that does not mean the find() function actually had time to return something.

Usually I solve it with some defensive code, i.e:

```
Template.chartEditPreview.rendered = function () {
  if(this.data)
    drawChart(".chart-container", this.data);
  // else do nothing until the next deps change
}
```

Of course this is not as clean as it should be, but as far as I know the only way to solve problems like this properly.

**Updated answer**
In this case we need a dependency to trigger rerun on data change. Iron router solves this for us:

```
Template.chartEditPreview.rendered = function () {
  var data = Router.current() && Router.current().data();
  if(data)
    drawChart(".chart-container", data);
  // else do nothing until the next deps change
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. So how do I make sure that the `if` statement eventually executes? Right now it's just getting skipped over entirely since `this.data` isn't actually there yet, and Template.rendered seems to only be executing once, on load.

Comment: @TomCardoso maybe put it inside a Tracker.autorun function

Comment: I think Tracker.autorun would work yes. Or you could use a Tracker.Dependency. Normally this is done automatically and transparently when you put your mongo find code inside the template.rendered function, but since you only use a reference to this.data, I suspect the rerun won't be triggered automatically.I will update the example with some code.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Combining this with an autorun as per @Ethaan and David Weldon's suggestion got the auto-redraw functionality I was hoping for. Man, what a roundabout way of getting the template to do what I needed. Thanks all.

Comment: Once you get it it's easy. I don't think you need an autorun by the way.

Answer (score 1):

add `this.ready()` into the `data:function`

```
 data: function () {
    if(this.ready()){
       return Charts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    }else{
       this.render('loading')
   }
  },
```

Something using `data` and `waitOn` could be a little bit tricky

```
Template.chartEditPreview.rendered = function() {
   Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
    drawChart(".chart-container", this.data);  
   },1000)  
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, still getting `null` for `this.data`. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: check answer update, sometimes using `template.xxx.rendered` its nos enough, try with this timeout

Comment: Oh God, hopefully there's another way. Setting a 1sec (or whatever) timeout will make this thing crazy slow.

Is there a way to structure this so that it's not reliant on `.rendered`? I'll need `drawChart()` to be called many times on a loaded page, each time the data object is revised. This would be easy if I could just do it in the HTML, but since D3 needs to do its drawing thing I'm not really sure how to approach this.

Comment: You say this.data sometimes return the object and sometimes not correct?

Comment: Correct. It seems to be some sort of race condition problem, where the template is rendering but the data isn't ready.

Comment: @sander van den Akker seems correctly try with timeout or `if(this.data !== undefined){}`